# Remove extra android.jar from project Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jar

My build.gradle file

```
 android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "########"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 40
            versionName "3.1.9"
        }
    }
```

[image]

I want to remove the extra android.jar and res from my project path.How can I do that? Of the android.jar's one belongs to version 23 (MarshMallow) and other belogs to 19(Kitkat).I would prefer to keep MarshMallow jar and remove the Kitkat jar.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the image below :

```
Right click on the project  -> Open Module Settings
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: my compile version is 23 still didn't solve my problem

Comment: Try  Build -> ReBuild project .